# "Holding" a socket open too long causes a new one to spawn

Tags: socket, unix-sockets

I am connecting to a socket via `nc -U`:

```
user@node:~$ sudo nc -U service\@name.18822.sock
user@node:~$ xmpp.status
user@node:~$ connected
```

If I "hold" this connection open too long, it will kick me back to the CLI and spawn a new socket. If I just echo a command into the socket like:

`echo xmpp.status | sudo nc -U service\@name.18822.sock`

then a new socket is never spawned. I am wondering why this behavior exists, as I'm thinking it's less process related and more Unix/Linux internals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in unix-sockets which will auto-close connections.  Either the server or client must be closing this.  Netcat has a `-w` option mentioned in [the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc):

> If a connection and stdin are idle for more than timeout seconds, then the connection is silently closed. The -w flag has no effect on the -l option, i.e. nc will listen forever for a connection, with or without the -w flag. The default is no timeout.

But you are not specifying this option so the default is for netcat to keep the connection open indefinitely.

Many servers have implicit timeout set on connections.  This is to prevent poorly written clients chewing through resources.  Alternatively it's possible something is resetting the server you're connecting to.  That would cause it to close all connections.

I'm not sure from your question what this port really is.  But in short this isn't really a linux/unix thing so much as a xmpp thing.